# Why is char distinct from signed char and unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c++11, char, signed, type-traits

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::is_same<int, int>::value = " << std::is_same<int, int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::is_same<int, signed int>::value = "<<std::is_same<int, signed int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::is_same<int, unsigned int>::value = " << std::is_same<int, unsigned int>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "std::is_same<char, char>::value = " << std::is_same<char, char>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::is_same<char, signed char>::value = " << std::is_same<char, signed char>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value = " << std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The result is :

```cpp
std::is_same<int, int>::value = 1
std::is_same<int, signed int>::value = 1
std::is_same<int, unsigned int>::value = 0
----
std::is_same<char, char>::value = 1
std::is_same<char, signed char>::value = 0
std::is_same<char, unsigned char>::value = 0
```

Which means that `int` and `signed int` are considered as the same type, but not `char` and `signed char`. Why is that ?

And if I can transform a `char` into `signed char` using `make_signed`, how to do the opposite (transform a `signed char` to a `char`) ?

Comment: Interesting, I knew `char` could be signed or unsigned, but I thought it would at least be equivalent to one of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [char!=(signed char), char!=(unsigned char)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436513/char-signed-char-char-unsigned-char)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Comment: other duplicates: [What does it mean for a char to be signed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/451375/995714), [Difference between signed / unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4337217/995714), [What is signed char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21545008/995714)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's by design, [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#fundamental) says `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are different types. I think you can use static cast for transformation.

Answer (score 34):

> There are **three distinct** basic character types: *char, signed char* and *unsigned char*.
> Although there are three character types, there are only two representations: signed and unsigned. The (plain)*char* uses one of these representations. Which of the other two character representations is equivalent to *char*  **depends on the compiler**.
>
> In an unsigned type, all the bits represent the value. For example, an 8-bit *unsigned char* can hold the values from 0 through 255 inclusive.
>
> The standard does not define how signed types are represented, but does specify that the range should be evenly divided between positive and negative values. Hence an 8-bit *signed char* is guaranteed to be able to hold values from -127 through 127.

---

***So how to decide which Type to use?***

> Computations using *char* are usually problematic. *Char*  is by default signed on some machines and unsigned on others. So we should not use (plain)*char* in arithmetic expressions. Use it only to hold characters. If you need a tiny integer, explicitly specify either *signed char* or *unsigned char*.

Excerpts taken from *C++ Primer 5th edition*, p. 66.

Comment: I know this post is from long time ago but this answer is identical to a paragraph in *C++ Primer*, second chapter.

Comment: @JerieWang I made an edit, this was effectively C++ Primer verbatim.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, the Standard is precisely telling that char, signed char and unsigned char are 3 different types. A char is usually 8 bits but this is not imposed by the standard. An 8-bit number can encode 256 unique values; the difference is only in how those 256 unique values are interpreted. If you consider a 8 bit value as a signed binary value, it can represent integer values from -128 (coded 80H) to +127. If you consider it unsigned, it can represent values 0 to 255. By the C++ standard, a signed char is guaranteed to be able to hold values -127 to 127 (not -128!), whereas a unsigned char is able to hold values 0 to 255.

When converting a char to an int, the result is implementation defined! the result may e.g. be -55 or 201 according to the machine implementation of the single char 'É' (ISO 8859-1). Indeed, a CPU holding the char in a word (16bits) can either store FFC9 or 00C9 or C900, or even C9FF (in big and little endian representations). Explicit casts to signed or unsigned char do guarantee the char to int conversion outcome.

Comment: I think all 11111111 (0xFF) stands for -1 as for signed char, not -128. I tried on VS.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to this horrible mistake. now fixed in the post. Indeed -128 is 80H and not FFH which is -1... its easy indeed to find the binary representation of a negative value. for 8 bits, just complement it 256, (for n bits, complement it 2 exp n) e.g. for -1: 256 - 1 = 255 = FFH. for -5: 256 -5 =  251 = FBH, and -128 yields 256 - 128 = 128 = 80H ... one can play with the old Windows Calculator set in programmers' mode.

Comment: Sadly some implementations chose the less intuitive default for `char`, treating characters as -128 to 127 instead of 0 to 255, even though no ANSI code chart ever used negative numbers (nor any Unicode ones). This leads to exploits and access violations when people use characters as indices into arrays, because a character like 'Ä' is treated as -42.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, for a 10 year old question, none of the existing answers actually addresses the question of "why?" but rather give developers useful information about using/selecting.

The three distinct `char` types are a necessary implication from another decision in the language - whether `char` is signed or unsigned is compiler implementation dependent.  Take this code:

```
void bar(signed char * argument) { }
void foo() {
  char data[16];
  bar(data);
}
```

If there were only two `char` types, this code would only compile if a compiler implementation chose signed `char`. You really don't want code's validity to depend upon the choices expressly given to compiler writers - there be dragons. It's better that this code never compile, which is easily accomplished by three distinct `char` types.

The same is not true for `int` and any of its `short`/`long`/`long long` brethren. `signed int` must be the same thing as `int`, but `unsigned int` is a separate type.

`char` is the only integer type whose base signed-ness is a compiler implementation detail, and the explicit type difference between `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` is to protect code validity from choices expressly given to compiler implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Adding more info about the range: Since c++ 20, -128 value is also guaranteed for signed char: [P1236R0: Alternative Wording for P0907R4 Signed Integers are Two's Complement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r0.html)

> For each value x of a signed integer type, there is a unique value y of the corresponding unsigned integer type such that x is congruent to y modulo 2N, and vice versa; each such x and y have the same representation.
>
> [ Footnote: **This is also known as [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).** ].
> [ Example: The value -1 of a signed type is congruent to the value 2N-1 of the corresponding unsigned type; the representations are the same for these values. ]
>
> The minimum value required to be supported by the implementation for the range exponent of each signed integer type is specified in table X.
>
> | Type | Minimum range exponent N |
> | --- | --- |
> | signed char | 8 |
> | short | 16 |
> | int | 16 |
> | long | 32 |
> | long long | 64 |

Hence, as a signed char has 8 bits: -2ⁿ⁻¹ to 2ⁿ⁻¹-1 (n equal to 8).

**Guaranteed range is from -128 to 127**. Hence, when it comes to range, there is no more difference between char and signed char.

---

About Cadoiz's comment: There is what the standard says, and there is the reality.
Reality check with below program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = -128;
    printf("%d\n", (int)c);
    printf("%d\n", (int)--c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-128
127
```

---

I would also say that signed char would help fellow programmers and also potentially the compiler to understand that you will use char's value to perform pointer's arithmetic.

Comment: Just for your concern: Tables are now supported - unfortunately, I wasn't able to take the freedom for an edit, the queue is full. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/390859 Attention, signed char only ranges from -127, not -128 to 127 - consider the other answers.

Comment: Tables are supported since November 2020, my answer is from April. And to affirm that signed char only ranges from -127 to 127 you need some evidence. Do you have any? I do, see my edit.

Comment: Both was not meant offensively, just as a hint - plus you ommited the keyword `signed` before `char`. On which platform did you test the code? My evidence is limited to my own experience with MS VS for x86 and x64, but I didn't try the most recent one. I absolutely agree with your opinion on preferring `(un)signed char` over `char` for arithmetics (or probably everything besides actual characters like `'a'`=.

Comment: I know I don't mean to be offensive as well, my point is: please show the output of trying the above program on your OS and show me the resulting output. The code was tested on Ubuntu (18.04)

Comment: Just a small note: https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1759
I will post real evidence as soon as I have time for that.

Comment: I am looking forward to it :)