# Why was the type of '\xe4' chosen to be char instead of unsigned char

Tags: c++, char, language-lawyer

I am learning C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I learnt that

> The signedness of `char` depends on the compiler and the target platform

This means that on one implementation/platform `char` might be `signed` and in another it might be `unsigned`. In other words, we **cannot portably write** `char ch = 228;` because the system in which `char` is `signed` `228` is out of range. For example, if you see [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bdzfj5Gv3) you'll see that we get a warning in clang.

---

Then I was surprised to learn that the type of `'\xe4'` is `char` and not `unsigned char`. I was surprised because `\xe4` corresponds to `228` which will be out of range for a system in which `char` is `signed`.   So I expected the type of `'\xe4'` to be an `unsigned char`.

Thus, **my question is** why did the standard choose to define the type of `'\xe4'` to be `char` instead of `unsigned char`. I mean `\xe4` is in range of  `unsigned char` but out of range for `char`(in a system where char is signed). So it seems natural/intuitive to me that `unsigned char` should've been used as the type of `'\xe4'` so that it won't have platform/implementation dependence.

---

##### Note

Note that I am trying to make sense of what is happening here and my current understanding might be wrong. I was curious about this and so have asked this question to clear my concept further, as I've just started learning C++.

Note also that my question is not about whether we can portably write `char ch = 228;` but instead that why is the type of `'\xe4'` chosen to be `char` inplace of `unsigned char`.

---

##### Summary

Why is the type of a character literal `char`, even when the value of the literal falls outside the range of `char`? Wouldn't it make more sense to allow the type to be `unsigned char` where the value fits that range?

Comment: __Suggestion:__ You might want to start your question with the question. I suggest the following summary of your query as I understand it: *"Why is the type of a character literal `char`, even when the value of the literal falls outside the range of `char`? Wouldn't it make more sense to allow the type to be `unsigned char` when the value fits that range?"* Then you could proceed with your examples using `228` and `\xe4`.

Comment: @JaMiT I've added it as summary.

Comment: A summary at the end helps people verify that they understood what they spent the time to read. A summary at the beginning helps people decide if they want to spend the time reading your question. I'd suggest starting with the summary in the hope of getting more people to read the question.

Comment: Speculatively (although consult **D&E** to see if it is mentioned) between 1979 and 1985 when Bjarne made the decision, *character literals* were expected to hold ASCII characters.  Which makes the range outside of 7-bit character literal values unusual.  The decision was also coupled with making character literals **char** rather than C **int**.  And **char** have platform determined *signedness*.

Comment: I checked the **D&E**, and it discussed the decision to make *character literals* be **char** rather than **int** (like they are in C).  But no mention of `'\xE4'` "out of range" concerns, just a more general point that there were no compatibility problems with the C and C++ difference.  The reason to make *character literals* be **char** was to support overloading; and also that `unsigned` had just been added to C so it was still novel at the time.

Comment: Ah, someone found a list of duplicates. Not sure if any really address this question, though, about why there is no promotion of character literals from `char` to `unsigned char`. It is probably the result of language evolution. There is also the possibility that it is desirable for the literal `'\xe4'` to have the same type on all systems, regardless of whether or not `char` is signed on those systems. Having different types strikes me as a worse incompatibility than possibly having different values.

Answer (score 0):

By language (C++) definition. The basic character literal is a `char` type. [Link to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). It can be found in the standard under [lex.ccon](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#def:literal,character,ordinary)

But for `char`, [basic.fundamental #7](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#7) states:

> Type "char" is a distinct type that has an implementation-defined choice of “signed char” or “unsigned char” as its underlying type.

Which again says that it depends on the implementation. This is also stated in other answers, e.g. [*Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097580) (It isn't)

And think about what the impact would be if a character literal in the extended ASCII range (*normal ASCII is 7 bit) would automatically be promoted to `unsigned char`... that would give all sort of difficult issues. e.g. What should happen if you append an `unsigned char` to a string of `signed char`?

But in the end, how important is it what the underlying type is? It's not that `char c = '\xe4'` is UB: It's perfectly defined behavior, as the string literal get converted to the same `char` type, negative or not. In operations strings it doesn't matter that much that chars can be negative, just like stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451392). **However**, [when sorting strings it will matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451387)

Comment: I already know that it is by language definition`char`. My question is why is it so when it doesn't make sense. Also I am not asking how to make it `unsigned char` either but rather questioning the standard's choice itself.

Comment: @Ronald _"why is it so when it doesn't make sense"_ which renders your question primarily opinion based. There are often, and many unlogical things in programming language designs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, this is not opinion based because if `'\xe4'` is char then `char ch = '\xe4';` would be unspecified behavior for systems where char is signed.

Comment: It's not "unspecified"; it's implementation-defined.

Comment: @JHBonarius You might want to look at [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post)