# Is char ch = '\xe4' unspecified or implementation defined

Tags: c++, char, language-lawyer

I am learning C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape#Notes) that:

> If the value represented by a single hexadecimal escape sequence does not fit the range of values represented by the character type used in this string literal (`char`, char8_t, (since C++20)char16_t, char32_t, (since C++11)or wchar_t), the result is **unspecified**.

(emphasis mine)

This means that, in a system where `char` is signed, the result of `'\xe4'` will be unspecified. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73754191/why-was-the-type-of-xe4-chosen-to-be-char-instead-of-unsigned-char#comment130237039_73754390) the person says that "it is implementation defined and not unspecified".

So, my question: Is the behavior of the below statements unspecified or implementation-defined? That is, is this an error in cppreferene's documentation or have I understood it incorrectly.

```
char arr[] = {'\xe4','\xbd','\xa0','\xe5','\xa5','\xbd','\0'}; //unspecified or implementation defined 
char ch = '\xef';                                              //unspecified or implementation defined
```

Comment: It appears you have understood it incorrectly.  For example, `'\x1234'` doesn't fit in the range of values represented by the character type.

Comment: It's implementation specified if `char` is signed or unsigned. So the actual "value" of e.g. `'\xe4'` might be something unexpected if `char` is signed.

Comment: With that said, `char` is usually one byte, which means `'\xe4'` will fit in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be either *implementation defined* (as per C++17) or (probably) *well defined* (as per C++23).

In C++17 (or earlier?), according to [this Draft Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 5.13.3 Character literals        [lex.ccon]
>
> …
> <sup>8</sup>     …
> The value of a character literal is implementation-defined if it falls
> outside of the implementation-defined range defined for `char` (for
> character literals with no prefix) or `wchar_t` (for character
> literals prefixed by `L`). …

However, from this [Draft C++23 Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon) (also **§5.3.13, [lex.ccon]**):

> <sup>3.2.3</sup>     Otherwise, if the
> *character-literal's* encoding-prefix
> is absent or `L`, and *v* does not exceed the range of representable
> values of the corresponding unsigned type for the underlying type of
> the character-literal's type, then the value is the unique value of
> the character-literal's type `T` that is congruent to *v* modulo
> *2<sup>N</sup>*, where *N* is the width of `T`.

So, in your case, as long as the value of the escaped sequence is representable by an `unsigned char`, then there is neither undefined nor implementation-defined behaviour, as of C++23. However, if that value is outside the range of that `unsigned` equivalent, then the literal is *ill-formed*:

> <sup>3.2.4</sup>     Otherwise, the *character-literal*
> is ill-formed.

---

Note: This [C++20 Draft Standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) has the same clause as the above-cited C++17 version (although it's paragraph 7, rather than 8).

Comment: Does this mean the cppreference is wrong? Because they said that it is unspecified.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to argue with the *person* (as it happens, a Stack Overflow moderator who knows a thing or two about C++) who said so.

Comment: I am not asking you to argue with anyone. Note that at the end of my question I have asked whether the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape#Notes) given is wrong because they(cppreference people) said that the behaviour is unspecified. That is, I am not asking you to argue with the SO moderator but instead asking about cpprefernce documentation.

Comment: Well, the answer to that is implicit in my answer, already. The fact that both Standards that I quote *specify* what happens means that, in neither case, is the behaviour *unspecified*.

Answer (score 1):

This concern was resolved by the adoption of [P2029R4 (Proposed resolution for core issues 411, 1656, and 2333; numeric and universal character escapes in character and string literals)](https://wg21.link/p2029) for C++23 at the October 2021 WG21 virtual plenary. See that paper for links to the relevant core issues.

The behavior is now well-defined. C++ now requires two’s complement representation for integer types (following the adoption of [P1236](https://wg21.link/p1236) for C++20). When `char` is a signed type, the result is the (unsigned) value of the numeric escape converted to a signed type. Whether the result is negative depends on the range of values representable by `char` (`char` may be larger than 8 bits).